# Restore firefox data

Tags: firefox

I've installed 20.04, so I copied firefox folder that is in Mozilla hidden folder inside home entirely from 16.04 and pasted on the same folder on new system. Is that the way it's meant to be? I don't know if I did something wrong Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is on-topic but according to Mozilla

1. Enter about:profiles in address bar
2. Create a new profile and then close firefox
3. Paste your old profile files in the new profile folder replacing any files there
4. Start firefox and you can set the new profile as default by going back to step 1

Comment: Yes it works. Another idea would be to close firefox, delete the `.mozilla` created folder and copy back the saved one. In both case, review files perms after copy

Comment: Thank you. I was afraid that .mozilla folder contained firefox browser itself, and that if I did that I would copy firefox version of 16.04 in 20.04, creating a mess.